# while read line into array, bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I read file, but data of array exist only in loop. At the end of code i try to echo tab[3], but it is empty.

```
ls -t > lista.txt
N=$(wc -l lista.txt)
N=${N:0:1}
tab[$N]=0


let I=0
while read line 
do
    tab[$I]="$line"
    echo ${tab[$I]}
    ((I+1))
done <lista.txt
echo ${tab[3]} #no Value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`((I+1))` doesn't change the value of `$I`. You have to assign the value to it

```
(( I = I + 1 ))
```

or use an increment

```
# You can use any of the following lines:
(( I++ ))
(( ++I ))
(( I += 1 ))
```

Comment: @Xalion: Yes, because $I stays 0 and it changes and shows `${tab[0]}` all the time.